# Tensorflw MultiRNNCell's parameter in doc ,I think it is wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow

I found in the [tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent):

`stacked_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * number_of_layers,
                ...`

I need to use MultiRNNCell

but, I write those lines

`a = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(10)]*3
print id(a[0]), id(a[1])`

Its output is `[4648063696 4648063696]`.

Can `MultiRNNCell` use the same object `BasicLSTMCell` as a list for parameter?

Comment: you can format your question so that it will be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiRNNCell` takes a list of [cells](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L668) as a parameter.

The `BasicLSTMCell` is an [RNN cell](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py#L124).

So yes, `MultiRNNCell` should be able to take a list of `BasicLSTMCell` objects as the `cell` parameter.

Comment: a = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(10)]*3 , a is a list of the same objects. the list need contain diffirent objects. see my issue,https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7604